# Online Solver for Prime Power Modulus problems

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve some problems nominated as a HW by our instructor. Problems are of the form:

$$f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$$

where $f(x)$ is a polynomial. My concern is to check the correctness of my solutions. Is there a website solving such problems online??

I am asking this question after a little unsuccessful research on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B2x-7+%3D+0+(mod+5%5E3)) does it. The syntax is like this:

```
x^3+2x-7 = 0 (mod 5^3)
```